# min distance in a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, distance

How would I find the min distance between two vertices in a graph.

What function should I use?

[image]

For example, in the above, $d(2,4)=2$ and $d(2,3)=1$

Comment: By "min distance", do you mean the length of the minimum path between to specified vertices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`GraphDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphDistance.html) to do that:

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1, 1 <-> 4}];

GraphDistance[g, 2, 3]
GraphDistance[g, 2, 4]
(* 1 *)
(* 2 *)
```